# How to configure bootstrap input spinner to change input's value when press + or - button only?

Tags: javascript

I use bootstrap input spinner such as below code.

In this case after i press `+` or `-` change event of input called repeatedly.

Is exist a way to configure bootstrap input spinner to call change event when press + or - buttons only?

```
 <input id="frequency" class="form-control" type="number" value="0" min="0" max="50" step="1" />
```

js

```
 $("input[type='number']").inputSpinner();
```

Answer (score 2):

You could simply increase the `autoInterval` option in the config to a high number such as `60000` which will make it so your input spinner will only increase when you've been holding the button for 1 minute like so:

```js
const config = {
  autoInterval: 60000
}

$("input[type='number']").inputSpinner(config);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://shaack.com/projekte/bootstrap-input-spinner/src/bootstrap-input-spinner.js"></script>

<input type="number" value="500" min="0" max="1000" step="10" />
```

Answer (score 0):

With version 3.0.3 of the bootstrap-input-spinner you can set the `autoInterval` property to `undefined`. This disables the auto change when holding a button.

```js
const config = {
  autoInterval: undefined
}
$("input[type='number']").inputSpinner(config);
```